# Adding a collapsible row in a pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

I have a `pageBlockTable` nested inside a `pageBlockSection` and I'm trying to nest a collapsible row inside the `pageBlockTable` that would pull in some related records based on the ID for each row in the `pageBlockTable`. I've tried adding another `pageBlockSection` which I could place either at the top or bottom of the `pageBlockTable`. However, I cannot find a way to place it so the collapsible row is underneath each row of the `pageBlockTable`. So, for each row of the `pageBlockTable` there would be a collapsible row directly underneath that when expanded would display related records of the ID for that row in the `pageBlockTable`.

Here is a section of the VF page code with the `pageBlockSection` and `pageBlockTable`

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Edit Purchase Order Lines" columns="1" id="infoSection">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="soLinesTable" value="{!salesOrderLinesForPage}" var="line">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Sales Order Line" width="10%">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!line.salesOrderLine.Id}">{!line.salesOrderLine.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Product SKU" width="10%">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!line.salesOrderLine.Product_SKU__c}" />
                    </apex:column>                   
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <div id="grandTotalContainer"><span id="grandTotalTitle">Grand Total:</span><span id="grandTotal"></span></div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
<style>
    .collapsed {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function toggleExpandRow(target) {
        target.querySelector('.grandTotalContainer').classList.toggle('collapsed');
    }
</script>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Edit Purchase Order Lines" columns="1" id="infoSection">
  <apex:pageBlockTable onRowClick="toggleExpandRow(this)" id="soLinesTable" value="{!salesOrderLinesForPage}" var="line">
    <apex:column headerValue="Sales Order Line" width="10%">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!line.salesOrderLine.Id}">
            {!line.salesOrderLine.Name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Product SKU" width="10%">
      <apex:outputField value="{!line.salesOrderLine.Product_SKU__c}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column breakBefore="true">
      <div class="grandTotalContainer collapsed">
        <span class="grandTotalTitle">Grand Total:</span>
        <span class="grandTotal"></span>
      </div>
    </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The trick here is to use `breakBefore` on the last column to force a new row, which we can then toggle when the parent row is clicked. This is just an example, there's plenty of other ways to do this, too.

This leaves a little space, you could also use a more complicated query selector to find the element to toggle, and you could also collapse them in other ways, too.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you @sfdcfox!